# Key Index Must Be Created Prior to Key Being Used

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, titan

Key Index Must Be Created Prior to Key Being Used

Before a key is used as a vertex property, a key index must be created for it if indexing is desired. This pitfall will be fixed in a future release.

Is there any way to overcome this limitation

Answer (score 0):

It should no longer be a limitation given Titan 0.5.x:

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.2/reindex.html

This is likely just a flaw in the documentation at this point.